# Facebook/Twitter "Like" buttons in pure html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to add share buttons to my simple website...

1. Is it possible to make a Facebook "like" button in pure html?
2. Is it possible to make a Twitter "like" button in pure html?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what makes a link "facebook-like" or "twitter-like"

Comment: @Gareth - I assume it means a button that allows the visitor to "Like" the page on facebook or "Tweet" it on twitter. Not "facebook-like" or "twitter-like" in appearance.

Comment: oh sorry!  I mean the facebook "like" link, people click on it to tell their friends they like a particular webpage I think...

Comment: You have asked for "pure HTML", by which I assume you mean no JavaScript, yet you have tagged with Javascript and PHP. Did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Facebook's developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web), insert the following into the body of your markup:

```
   <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

(make sure you close the iframe tag, on the [facebook website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web) it is left open.)

And for twitter (found on a [forum](http://www.warriorforum.com/programming-talk/114098-how-do-i-put-tweet-button.html)):

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=Enter status message here" 
 title="Click to send this page to Twitter!" target="_blank">Tweet This!</a>
```

Comment: Thats an iframe, is their a way to use pure html?

Comment: It's not possible to do this with the facebook share or like button. It used to be possible by just using the `src` referenced within the `iframe`. However, the new like is driven purely by AJAX, hence the iframe. You're out of luck on the Facebook side of things.

Answer (score 5):

The [Tweet Button](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton) is the recommend way for twitter, although a simple link like this works too, if you want to share a link:

- http://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com&text=Some%20tweet%20text

Similar, `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=` allows to share an URL as well.

There are probably more ways to share without using JavaScript (I remember some feature that preset the tweet text on the twitter homepage, but can't find it right now).